# Force install of Crystal Reports 32-bit runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2010, x86, 64-bit, setup-project, crystal-reports-2010

I have a `Winforms` application that is compiled for 32-bit (x86), which has a setup project that also targets x86.

[image]

I have `SAP Crystal Reports, version for Visual Studio (version 13.0.13)` installed on my development machine and in the setup project, under dependencies I have `Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .Net Framework` option checked. Also `Windows Installer 3.1` is checked as a dependency.

[image]

Installing on 32 bit machines give no problem, but when I install on a 64-bit machine for some reason the installer installs the 64-bit version of the `Crystal Reports Runtime Engine`. The application then gives an exception when you try print a report because it needs the 32-bit version installed. If I manually go install the 32-bit version of `Crystal Reports` runtime then the reports work correctly, but I want the install of `Crystal Reports` to work correctly from the application installation.

So my question here is two-fold: 1) Does anyone know whether this issue I am having is a `Windows Installer` issue or is it specifically a `Crystal Reports` issue? 2) How can I specify in the `Visual Studio` setup project that the 32-bit version of the Crystal Reports runtime should **always** be installed, even when installing on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: If it's your app, is it difficult to build a 64-bit version for 64-bit machines? Not ideal perhaps, but maybe would solve this issue. It's often the case that 64-bit runtimes contain both 64-bit and 32-bit components because people run 32 and 64-bit apps on 64-bit machines. It's a bit odd that CR doesn't do that and requires you to install both runtimes.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the process that need to be done. Please see the [link](http://www.sdn.sap.com/notes?id=0001553482&boj=/sap/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes.do?access=69765F6D6F64653D3939382669765F7361706E6F7465735F6E756D6265723D30303031353533343832) for more details.

**Resolution**

Find the **Product.xml** file in the bootstrapper folder:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0

Comment out the below BypassIf entry to install the 32bit version CRRuntime redist on the target machine

```
<!--  ByPass if the Processor is not x86 --> 
<BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="Intel" />
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the link. I will test this sometime. At the moment though this is no longer an issue for us because we resolved it by making a copy of the 32bit CR and giving the copy the same name as the 64bit CR. This way it did not matter which installer was used because they were both 32bit CR. A bit of a hack solution, I readily admit, but it worked for us.